# Do wild animals really "appear" in the night?

Tags: meaning, phrases, animals

(I've attempted to post this several times in the "biology" category, but they keep harassing me and closing it as "off-topic" even though it couldn't be more on-topic, and the only other category I can think of is this.)

I've heard this "saying" in my language which roughly translates into:

> The really wild animals come out at night!

It seems to be a double meaning, referring to "wild animals" as in extroverted humans who party at night.

However, is this also a thing on the savanna or other places where there are "really wild animals", such as lions and tigers?

All I know about lions is that the lionesses do all the hunting and the male lions sleep for like twenty hours a day and are only active for four. However, I thought those hours when they are awake are during the day? Not the night?

So is there any "animal kingdom" relevance to the saying that "wild animals come out at night"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't about the English Language (it's a question about animal behaviour that just happens to be in English).

Comment: Night feeders like lions and house cats are called nocturnal. In a sentence: "Sorry other sites gave you a hard time, but how that becomes our fault is nocturnal."

Comment: It sounds like a saying and wild animals is used metaphorically.  A person shows their "claws and fangs" when there are few people to witness it.

Comment: In the context of wild animals in the night, "appearing" and "coming out" have two different meanings.

Comment: What do you think "really wild animals" means, as compared to simply "wild animals"? There are certainly plenty of nocturnal wild animals - I'm sure Google could provide a long list

Answer (score 0):

> The really wild animals come out at night!

The literal meaning is The *most savage* animals come out *[of their dens]* at night *[in order to hunt]*!

The figurative meaning is

The *people that are really crazy/who party the hardest, etc*. come out *[of their homes and onto the streets]* at night!

As you see - the example is a play on words.